# Getting Django request.user in Angular Module

Tags: angularjs, django, http, request

I am new to Angular, and trying to figure out how the best way to do this is. In my Django view, I authenticate a user, storing that user in request.user. Is there a way to retrieve that request.user in an Angular module. Can I retrieve it through Angular's $http service ? Looked around, but couldn't find a solution to this...yet, and thought I would try good ole Stack Overflow.

```
function bindPusher() {
            var defer = $q.defer();

        var channelName = 'private-account-' + Session.account.id;
        var channel = $pusher.client.subscribe(channelName);

        channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function (data) {
            $log.debug('Pusher subscribed: ' + channel.name);
            PushListener.bindAndListen(channel);
            defer.resolve(data);
        });
        channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function (status) {
            if (status === 403) {
                var msg = 'Pusher channel not authorized.';
                $log.warn(msg);
                defer.reject(msg);
            }
        });

        return defer.promise;
    }
```

Comment: is your angular running on your django server (using angular in the Django templates) or is it separate?

Comment: also, if you're using angular within django, are you using a specific package?

Comment: Yes, my Angular is running on my Django server, and I'm not entirely sure if Im using a specific package, examples ?

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the user in Angular?

Comment: The previous auth was using Pusher, and was using the account id to get the channel name. Admittedly, Im not fully sure what Pusher does, so I will append the angular code to the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular runs in the browser, Django runs on the server. Use a JSON string to send the data of Django's `request.user` to the browser, where Angular can unwrap that JSON string into a Javascript object.

So, you are correct, `$http.get('/path/my-user.json')` could read the `request.user`'s data.

```
$http.get('/path/my-user.json').then(function (response) {
  $scope.user = response.data.user;
}, function (reject) {
  // error
});
```

In your Django view, you would send the data as a JSON encoded string.

```
def my_view(request):
    data = {'username': request.user.username,
            'is_staff': request.user.is_staff}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

But, these are Django and Angular, so there are many things to automate much of this, once you understand the basics. Namely [Django Restframework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and the [Angular Resource Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Comment: Ahhhh I see, I was curious why he was using 'window' to get the account id in one part of his code. I'll admit I am very new to angular, but its starting to make more and more sense.